# Get the list of Git branches for a repository hosted on GitHub

Tags: git, github, github-api

Is there a command line way of getting the list of branches available in a repository hosted in GitHub (without creating and running commands from within a clone)?

I tried using [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) on the URL that shows the branches list and getting the content.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
git ls-remote --heads <repo-url>
```

[Man page of `git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote).

For example, to get the branches of Git's Git repository, use

```
git ls-remote --heads git://github.com/git/git.git
```

Output:

```
121f71f0da1bc9a4e1e96be2c3e683191a82a354    refs/heads/maint
f623ca1cae600e97cb0b38131fdd33e4fb669cf8    refs/heads/master
8e148144574e6c6511b591286e44a677a260d760    refs/heads/next
fcdb578342aeaf355c296026af08093b20aab9b4    refs/heads/pu
5321cb29c8f709669c5e4a04f502cd984623592c    refs/heads/todo
```

Answer (score 15):

Using the GitHub API:
Send a GET HTTP request to
`https://api.github.com/repos/`username`/`reponame`/branches`.

The reply should be an array of objects, which have the `name` attribute being the branch name.

Source: *[List branches](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branches#list-branches)*

Comment: But it doesn't return protected branches along with the other branches. How to do that ? I also tried the GET request with protected: true. Even then, I didn't get the protected branches. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @user2125722 You probably _are_ doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is. Please ask a new question containing the _exact_ URL that you were requesting (feel free to replace the _username_ and _reponame_ with "username" and "reponame" if that's private info) and what it's giving you back (again, as exact as possible but if it's private info feel free to replace sections of it with `...` or something similar). Then give me a link to the question so that I can have a look at it.