# Trigger build in Jenkins when git branches are created or deleted

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a job in Jenkins for a project on GitHub, that I would like to be triggered whenever a new branch is created or an existing branch has been removed. Is this possible?

Notice: The Jenkins server is located internally in a company, so we can't use web hooks from GitHub.

Comment: How do you connect (protocol) to GitHub from Jenkins?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to write a script for it. Based on the ls command http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911923/get-list-of-git-branches-for-a-repo-hosted-on-github

Comment: @Technext via SSH, because it's a private repository.

Comment: Hi Tobias, can you elaborate on what you are trying to do. Why do you want builds at those events? What branches are you building? Best, Anders

Comment: @anders.norgaard the job I want to trigger uses Jenkins Jobs DSL to create build jobs for each branch. So basically this job should run every time there a branch is added or remove, to make sure we have matching build jobs for all branches. Currently we just run the job on a schedule, but I was wondering if there was a smarter way. Ideally the Git server would notify the Jenkins server, but we don't have a setup that allows for that at this time.

Comment: Ok. See attempt at answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of one approach, you may use.

Using Job DSL Plugin allow you to create or delete projects using Groovy. It is not hard to include github scanning and create jobs from that. Good thing about it is, that it recognizes deleted jobs as well.

I.e. Install Job DSL plugin, create a seed job (free-style) with a regular trigger, and paste something akin the below into your script..

```
def project = 'nbn/griffon-maven-plugin'
def branchApi = new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/${project}/branches")
def branches = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(branchApi.newReader())


branches.each { 
    def branchName = it.name
    job {
        name "${project}-${branchName}".replaceAll('/','-')
        scm {
            git("git://github.com/${project}.git", branchName)
        }
        steps {
            maven("test -Dproject.name=${project}/${branchName} ")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, actually it's the jobs DSL job I want to run whenever branches are created or destroyed. Right now it just runs on intervals, and that also works fine. Just wondered if I could make it only run when there was a reason to.

Comment: You would still have to poll either way. Job DSL should not have too much overhead of parsing the entire configuration, and should dirty-check correctly, so although Technext explanation is good, it is probably just overhead that needs to be maintained somehow. If you have suggestions for Job DSL always feel free to drop a comment or two.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this approach if it looks good to you. :)

Schedule a cron on the build machine to perform the following task:

1. Fetch list of branch from the Git repository and store it in a file, say *branch_list*

   We use Gitolite and access branch names using `git ls-remote` command.

   `git ls-remote gitolite@git.server.com:repository_name`

   For example,

   ```
   [tom@master ~]$ git ls-remote gitolite@git.server.com:repository_name
   08a119f0aec5d4286708d2e16275fcd7d80d2c25        HEAD
   a91ef29f1be5bfe373598f6bb20d772dcc65b8ca        refs/heads/dev-mob
   d138356cf752a46fd8c626229809c9eaae63a719        refs/heads/dev-ssorel
   e7d7e2c617c4a42b299b29c0119283813800f1bb        refs/heads/dev-omni
   3193b36d678f1af2dcc3a291c6313f28ede97149        refs/heads/dev-pay
   72fd9d8586708011c763cd7bc4f7bd2a3513a12f        refs/heads/dev-sell
   39455fc2672039a7f325e9cafe3777ed563368ef        refs/heads/dev-apis
   a22eb000ffa1ac0fbbf51b6bc8aea31b040567a3        refs/heads/dev-front
   78a63105ec754d7ba758af97d542e749ceb9c533        refs/heads/dev-tpsp
   82d99796690b6c562872ea68655c74ebc3f0abfb        refs/heads/mainline
   fd82522f9999cedb11e245b515d480187c2e9cc6        refs/heads/master
   ```

   To filter out *only* the branch names, you can use:

   ```
   [tom@master ~]$ git ls-remote gitolite@git.server.com:repository_name | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f3 | sort > branch_list_latest
   ```
2. Do a diff with the *last* fetched file i.e., *branch_list*. If there is a difference, then trigger the build. You can either use `diff` or `cmp` command.

   ```
   git ls-remote gitolite@git.server.com:repository_name | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f3 | sort > branch_list_latest

   if ! cmp -s branch_list branch_list_latest; then
      mv branch_list_latest branch_list
      echo "Files differ which means branch created or removed. Triggering build..."
      # Trigger build command
   fi
   ```

Cron will keep fetching the list of branches after certain interval. You can define the interval as per your need.

Comment: to filter only branches you can do: git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:org/repo

Comment: Thanks @GuillemoMansilla. Just tried it. It seems i will still have to extract the branch name, isn't it?

Comment: sorry, I forgot one part of the command git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:org/repo | cut -d/ -f3

Comment: which is basically the same thing you posted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Where I am now we have two long-lived branches, and the rest is almost exclusively short-lived feature branches.

We already have jobs for the long-lived branches.

For the feature branches I have looked at

https://pythonhosted.org/jenkins-autojobs/

and

http://entagen.github.io/jenkins-build-per-branch/

and found that they are both slightly too complicated for our use.

Instead I set up one job with the branch-specifier "*_build" for the convention that if you push a branch ending with "_build" it will be built by Jenkins. Next step is remembering that when you review, the pull request better be named "xyz..._build" :)

Best,
Anders

Answer (score 0):

According to https://jenkins-ci.org/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/ you should be able to create and delete a job depending on the creation and removal of a branch.

I haven't tried it, though...

You might also want to read https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/04/generated-jenkins-jobs-and-automatic-branch-merging-for-feature-branches/